# Squeaky noise coming from rear derailleur or jockey wheels

Tags: road-bike, derailleur-rear

I have this horrible squeaky noise coming from my rear deraileur area. It only happens when I pedal. Watch below for the video.

Comment: Looks clean and tidy - what do you oil the chain with and how often?

Comment: I use dry muck off lube, it works pretty well

Comment: I think this is coming from the pulley wheels. You could take them off and lube/grease them or pour lube into/over the silver washer/dustcup thing and hope it penetrates far enough.

Comment: @Michael I'd be cautious about just pouring lube into the area. Lubricant does attract dirt and grime, which then forms a grinding paste for the chain. Better to remove the jockey wheels and clean under the dust covers, then lubricate directly.

Comment: @WeiwenNg: Of course it’s always a good idea to wipe off the excess.

Comment: I've asked pretty mch the same question - https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/66474/weird-whistling-from-the-rear-derailleur and I guess the answer is also the same - it's from jockey wheels. I've cleaned them, that helped

Answer (score 6):

Sounds like jockey wheel squeak to me.

Although keeping your bike clean is generally a good thing, it does have some negative side effects like washing away grease and lubrication on your moving parts.

As part of your regular maintenance tasks you should be periodically replacing the lost/contaminated lubrication from your moving parts, in this case, likely to be your jockey wheels. Here is a [GCN Video on how to service your jockey wheels](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=57gu6H3YEHM)

Answer (score 1):

Clean and lube the chain. If that does not work service the jockey wheels.

Here's Park Tools page for derailleur service: https://www.parktool.com/blog/repair-help/rear-derailleur-overhaul

If/when you do take the jockey wheels out, keep track of which is the top and bottom wheel and which way around they go. The top and bottom wheels are different and some derailleur's wheels have a direction of rotation.

Comment: Should I use lithium Grease?

Comment: @Nicksamios No, use a light lube like the Park Tool article says

Answer (score 0):

I cleaned the chain today with the Park tool CM 52. It fixed the squeaky noise, not sure how a dirty chain caused that noise.

Comment: When it rains, the squeak on my garden gate goes away

Comment: Yes, water is a lubricant. The trouble is that it dries quickly and can cause rusting of ferrous parts.